# Confusing JSLINT Error

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm making a JavaScript dice roller for a tabletop strategy game that my friends and I play, but I've hit a snag. Basically there is an irregular hit table, so I can't use a formula (as far as I can tell) to judge the result, instead I've got a whole bunch of switch and if .. else statements to determine if they were successful or unsuccessful.
Because of the large amount of
I've corrected all other errors that JsLint has shown, but these errors I can't seem to make any sense of, as the characters they reference are in the middle of words.

Here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UEKh6/10/

```
Error:
Problem at line 19 character 12: Missing semicolon.
var aContnt["<h1>Broken History - Dice roller tool</h1><p>Choose one of the f...

Problem at line 19 character 1249: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
var aContnt["<h1>Broken History - Dice roller tool</h1><p>Choose one of the f...

Implied global: prompt 64,66,262,264,441, morale 441,443, iRoll 442,443
```

Comment: @rlemon - I removed it. I decided you're right and that it's only worth posting if it already covers the error message in question. Thanks.

Comment: can't you see the error above?

Comment: @MavericktheBroken1 - Yes, it's visible here. We were talking about my previous comment (now deleted) which referenced a site that lists JSLint error messages, but not the one in your question yet.

Comment: @JamesAllardice - Sorry didn't see that reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need a `=` sign between the start of your array and the variable declaration.

`var aContnt = ["`

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/UEKh6/14/ see with added `=`

Comment: input boxes appear but the first and second buttons do nothing afterwards :/

Comment: that is a new issue - your question was about the JSLint error and this was the cause of both errors. Please if you still have issues accept this one and start a new question.

Comment: however to start you off with a hint: all of your 'try again' buttons are broken HTML... another case of missing `=` sign. `onclick'tryagain()` should be `onclick='tryagain()`

Comment: *fixed the buttons, no effect, time for a new question methinks, goes to show though when you type fast you miss things!